# Group product and Bundle product has price display issues

Tags: bundled-product, grouped-products, pricing, product-view-page

When I create a bundle or a group product, the pricing is at the bottom and not on the right as shown in simple and downloadable.

The price is shown after the description with add bundle to cart and before related products.

Any ideas on how to have this at the top?